# Display child page on parent

Tags: page-template

This question has been asked a couple of times and previous answers have helped me get where I am.

**The goal:**

Display direct child page on parent page regardless of level

Example:

> parent 1
>
> -child 1
>
> --child 1.1

parent 1 displays child 1

child 1 display child 1.1

The current situation:

parent 1 displays child 1

child 1 doesn't display child 1.1 (it gets data of child 1 (current page) instead)

My current code is as follow:

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc', 'parent' => $post->ID ) );
                foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
            $content = $page->post_content;
            if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
                continue;

            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
        ?>

        <a  class="figurelink" href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><figure class="figsmall">

            <img src=" <?php the_field('thumb', $page->ID); ?> " width="207" height="141" alt="0" data-width-desktop="920" data-height-desktop="215" data-cssclass-desktop="desktop" data-width-mobile-high-res="920" data-height-mobile-high-res="215" data-cssclass-mobile-high-res="mobile-high-res"  data-width-mobile-low-res="768" data-height-mobile-low-res="179" data-cssclass-mobile-low-res="mobile-low-res">
                                <figcaption class="figsmall"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></figcaption>        
                            </figure></a>                               
          <?php }?></div>
        </div>
```

Note that `the_field()`is getting  custom field

This code is in a page template used by parent and child.

Hope this is clear and you guys can give me a hand.

Comment: Have you tried removing `'parent' => $post->ID ` from the get_pages parameters? and/or removing `'child_of' => $post->ID` (leaving in the parent parameter)?

Comment: yes if i remove    'parent' => $post->ID    it displays every child and subchild (i only want direct child) on child page it  displays child as well as current page (weird)

Comment: removing     'child_of' => $post->ID    has no effect, therefore i can actually get rid of it. but it doesnt help

Answer (score -1):

The problem was only with one set of `parent-child`. Deleting them and recreating the page solved the issue.